# How to get a value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 2340
            [node_created] => 1390349535
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 1176
            [node_created] => 1390086303
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 1133
            [node_created] => 1390086313
        )

)
```

How can I get the value after [nid] in part [1]?

Comment: `$myArray[1]->nid`.... please try reading the PHP manual: the section entitled `Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax` in the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) may help

Comment: @Wrikken true enough, fixing

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thanks for the link! I'm new to php and I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value = $array[1];
echo $value->nid;
```

I believe this should grab the value you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing something like below:

```
<?php

$o = (object)array("nid"=>123);
// Adding $o three times to the array to illustrate the idea.
$myArray = array($o, $o, $o);
echo $myArray[1]->nid;

?>
```

You're working with an anonymous object instance. In which case you would access the value as you would any other object by using `->`.